# php regex string between

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, between

I have this string:

```
<span itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">gegi123</span></span>
```

and i need `gegi123`

I tried this:

```
/<span itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">(.*?)</span></span>/
```

but that shows an error:

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '/' in /var/www/post/main.php on line 29
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the [pattern delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to match it literally by a backslash or pick another delimiter.

> Unknown modifier '/' ...

Everything after the closing delimiter is considered [modifiers/flags](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
/<span itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"...
↑ opening delimiter                                  ↑ closing delimiter
                                                      ↑ php don't know modifier /
```

With another delimiter: `~<span`...`http://`... `~`
 By escaping delimiter: `/<span`...`http:\/\/`... `/`